# Spring MVC Test empty json

Tags: json, spring-test

How can I test for an empty JSON response from a rest endpoint. I was hoping for something along the lines:

```
    ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(..);
    actions.andExpect(jsonPath("$", empty()));
```

obviously this fails as `{}` is not exactly empty.
Any advice?

Answer (score 16):

Try this one:

```
 ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(..);
 actions.andExpect(content().string("[]"));
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(..);
actions.andExpect(content().string(""));
```

Answer (score 3):

In JSON, `{}` is a non-null, but empty, object. This translates into Java as an empty map. You can validate that a JSON element is non-null and empty like this:

`actions.andExpect(jsonPath("$").value(Collections.EMPTY_MAP))`

Answer (score 1):

The `exists()` method worked well for me.

```java
this.mockMvc.perform(get("....")).andExpect(jsonPath("$").exists());
```

Answer (score 1):

.andExpect(jsonPath("$").isEmpty());

is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be tested using an empty map provided with the "jsonpathresultmatchers".

```
    ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(..);
actions.andExpect(jsonPath("$", anEmptyMap()));
```